# Gender specific words for female socialite and male socialite?

Tags: word-request

Is there a single word for a female socialite? 
Is there a single word for a male socialite?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you  please describe what it means you told us that it was not in english but you did not help us understand its meaning or even the language in.

Comment: It was created by me. :)

Comment: You mean you made a word? What does it mean?

Comment: What do you call Paris Hilton?

Comment: Honestly, I can't think of a gender specific version of socialite that doesn't have a lot of additional meaning attached to it. Maybe someone else will have some ideas.

Comment: I don't think you should have edited "socialitette" out of your question - I think it helps illustrate what you're looking for. Maybe say "I was thinking of something like socialitette, but I know that isn't an English word."

Comment: Check this link [***socialite***](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/socialite).

Comment: I think maybe you should also add your example of "Paris Hilton" as an illustration of how you understand socialite. She certainly wouldn't be described as a gentlewoman as the thesaurus might suggest :)

Comment: The word for "female socialite" is "debutante.' The male equivalent is 'beau.' Commenting on this old, closed question because there's a specific answer in both cases, and I don't understand why this question was closed.

Answer (score 1):

[man about town](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/man%20about%20town)

and

[woman about town](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/woman%20about%20town?s=t)

Comment: Thanks. But single words would be less awkward.

Comment: It depends, of course, on how one defines "word." Many people can accept [compound words](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/compound_word) with a space in between the elements as a *single word*. (For example: *school bus* and *doggie bag*) Or, one can connect the elements with hyphens: man-about-town. You can look at the thesaurus entries for my suggestions and see if you find others that you like better. And I am not sure what you mean by "awkward." To me, using *playboy* and *playgirl* might be awkward.